# Is it possible to put variables in my query not using string interpolation?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

Ok so I have an SQL request using string interpolation and running perfectly :

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE my_table SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('#{my_table.longitude}'::numeric, '#{my_table.latitude}'::numeric), 4326)::geography WHERE id=#{id}")
```

What I want to do is using SQL variables instead of string interpolation (for security reasons (SQL injections)) but I have been into some troubles with my query :

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE my_table SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(':longitude'::numeric, ':latitude'::numeric), 4326)::geography WHERE id=#{id}", longitude: my_table.longitude, latitude: my_table.latitude)
```

The error I get is :

> PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type
>   numeric: ":longitude" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

Is there a way to use SQL variables properly in the last query ?

Answer (score 0):

String interpolation this way is very dangerous and can open your server up to [SQL injection attacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection). Instead use [ActiveRecord's query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) to build the query, something like this:

```
my_table = MyTable.find(id)
my_table.update(location: "ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('#{my_table.longitude}'::numeric, '#{my_table.latitude}'::numeric), 4326)::geography")
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that tomorrow and report my results :)

Comment: Okay so I tried and I get some syntax errors as a result : `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...:geography", my_table.longitude, my_table.latitude)
`

Comment: Ah, looks like a syntax error. I updated the answer to correct it (I can't test it but it looks correct). This answer is still SQL injection-safe because the interpolated text is passed as an hash value to the updates command, which will sanitize the query.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using Active Record?

With your scenario, you appear to be taking values from other attributes in the record to populate a third `location` attribute.

Assuming you have a model in your application which is backed by this table, you have a couple of options:

1. Create a `location` method on the model which generates and returns the location based on the coordinates. An advantage here is less duplication of data in your DB, at the cost of being able to search natively against that generated location and the potential savings if the generation of that location is expensive.
2. Add a `before_save` callback to generate the location each time the record is saved (created or updated). This might cause issues if the generation is expensive and you update your records frequently ... however there are ways around this through checking whether the coordinates have changed before generating the location.

However, both of these solutions require you to write a method in your model to generate a location from the coordinates, or at least call some 3rd-party code to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I tried to use this method instead (and it seems to work as expected) :

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
@connection.prepare('fill_column_location', "UPDATE my_table SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint($1::numeric, $2::numeric), 4326)::geography WHERE id=$3")
fill_column_location = @connection.exec_prepared('fill_column_location', [my_table.longtmp, my_table.latitmp, id])
```

I don't know if there's any danger or flaws of doing that way.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sanatize_sql_array` worked for me in 2020. I think in this case you would do something like:

```rb
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.sanatize_sql_array([
  "UPDATE my_table SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint('?'::numeric, '?'::numeric), 4326)::geography WHERE id=?", 
  my_table.longitude, 
  my_table.latitude, 
  id
])

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_array

Answer (score -1):

Try '?' instead of interpolation

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE my_table SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint( ? , ? , 4326)::geography WHERE id= ? ", "#{my_table.longitude}::numeric", "#{my_table.latitude}::numeric)", id  )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's giving me a `wrong number of arguments (4 for 1...2) (ArgumentError)`

Comment: Or build the query using interpolation first then pass it into ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: String interpolation works perfectly (as seen before) but I don't want to use it. Also I already use ActiveRecord::Base